# External API issue in production - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I build an app rendering data from an external API. In development mode everything works fine but in production the API doesn't load. It does't return anything not error in console.

```js
axios.get("https://api.github.com/repos/....")
  .then(response => ...)
  .catch(error => console.log(error))

axios.get("https://api.github.com/...")
  .then(response => {
      ....
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Please create a code sandbox, would be far easier to troubleshoot

Comment: Maybe you forgot to install `axios` on your production environment

Comment: @Eldshe He said no error in the console

Comment: Check below the full code

Comment: In development, it work fine! I have enabled CORS in express

Answer (score 0):

You should check the network tab in the console and see which response code that request is returning. The catch block will only be hit if the response code of that request is one of these client errors listed on this website: https://httpstatuses.com/

Answer (score 0):

Full code here

Note In development mode.

My signup form work fine, login work fine
But in production none of this work!
I have google during for one week but dont find answer.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ShowCase from './utils/table.github.user';
import Validator from "../mm-admin/auth/auth.validator"
const Homepage = () => {

const [organisations, setOrgnisations] = useState([])

const [searchContributor, setSearchContributor] = useState('');
const [searchContributorResult, setSearchContributorResult] = useState([]);

const [isAdded, setAdded] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    let cleanup = false;
    requestApi()
    return () => {
        cleanup = true;
    }

}, [searchContributor])

const requestApi = () =>{
    axios.get("https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/contributors", {
        params : {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,//add when working with https sites
            requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
            agent: false,//add when working with https sites
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        const all = response.data;
        const result = all.filter(contributor => {
            return contributor.login.toLowerCase().includes(searchContributor.toLowerCase())
        })
        setSearchContributorResult(result)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
    axios.get("https://api.github.com/organizations",  {
        params : {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,//add when working with https sites
            requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
            agent: false,//add when working with https sites
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        const all = response.data;
        const result = all.filter(contributor => {
            return contributor.login.toLowerCase().includes(searchContributor.toLowerCase())
        })
        setOrgnisations(result)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
const makeSearchContr = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setSearchContributor(event.target.value)
}
const addFavorite = (favorite, notes) => event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (Validator.isAuthenticated()) {
        const id = Validator.isAuthenticated().user._id;
        const favorites = {
            item : JSON.stringify(favorite),
            note : notes
        }
        axios.put("/user/action/" + id, favorites)
        .then(res => {
            setAdded(true)
            const timer = setTimeout(() => {
                setAdded(false)
            }, 4000)
           return () => clearTimeout(timer)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    } else {
        console.log("Need to loged")
    }
}
const contributorGit = () => {
    return searchContributorResult.map((contributor, index) => {
        return <ShowCase key={index} item={contributor} status={isAdded} favorite={addFavorite}/>
    })
}
const organisationsGit = () => {
    return organisations.map((organisation, index) => {
        return <ShowCase key={index} item={organisation} favorite={addFavorite}/>
    })
}
return (
    <article>
        <div className="">
                <div className="container">
                    <form>
                        <div className="">
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search" value={searchContributor} onChange={makeSearchContr}/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div className="github-user" id="github">
            <div className="container">
                <h2>List contributor :</h2>
                <ul style={{paddingLeft : '0px'}}>
                    {contributorGit()}
                </ul>
                <h2>List organisation :</h2>
                <ul style={{paddingLeft : '0px'}}>
                    {organisationsGit()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
)
}
export default Homepage;
```